# How to get a CView based Windows that do not contain title bar and status bar

Tags: mfc, dialog, statusbar, titlebar, cview

I am writing MFC application, I choose CView based application other then Dialog based application. I don't know how to remove title bar and status bar, is there any method to do this? And made a CView based application just like dialog based application ?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Status bar can be removed by deleting all references to the CStatusBar member in your MainFrm class.

Title bar, what do you mean - the menu, the toolbar or the caption bar? First two you remove by commenting out the relevant parts in OnCreate() of CMainFrm, the last one I'm not 100% but I think you can do it by modifying cs.style in PreCreateWindow of your CMainFrm. Set the style to WS_DLGFRAME, that should work I think.